# Compare Equality of Object Key Values with Null

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm using the following code to compare two objects and its key value pairs to assure equality. It works great except it doesn't handle `null` values in fields. I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

How could I enhance this to support `null` values and why does this not work.

Example of expected behavior:

```
const o1 = {id: 123, name: Brian}
const o2 = {id: 456, name: null}

const objectsEqual = (o1, o2) => 
    typeof o1 === 'object' && Object.keys(o1).length > 0 
        ? Object.keys(o1).length === Object.keys(o2).length 
            && Object.keys(o1).every(p => objectsEqual(o1[p], o2[p]))
        : o1 === o2;

objectsEqual(o1,o2)
//returns false
```

Comment: To check for null-- You can simply use `!== null` as part of your conditional ..

Comment: null is an object, so it's trying to do things with its keys.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is "null is an object in javascript"
So when you say `typeof o1 === 'object'` it evaluates to true, then it tries to evaluate `Object.keys(o1).length` and throws error here
There can be a simplest solution for this

```js
const objectsEqual = (o1, o2) => JSON.stringify(o1) == JSON.stringify(o2);
```

If you want to fix your method, then you can change it as below

```js
const objectsEqual = (o1, o2) => 
    o1 !== null && o2!== null && typeof o1 === 'object' && Object.keys(o1).length > 0 
        ? Object.keys(o1).length === Object.keys(o2).length 
            && Object.keys(o1).every(p => objectsEqual(o1[p], o2[p]))
        : o1 === o2;
```

Comment: Note that `JSON.stringify` doesn't work for functions.

Comment: …and also not for objects with a custom `toJSON` method, and also not for objects that had their properties defined in a different order